# What causes siunitx and ot-tableau to be incompatible?

Tags: siunitx, linguistics, tabu

[`ot-tableau`](https://ctan.org/pkg/ot-tableau) is a package to produce optimality-theoretic tableaux for use in linguistics. These are basically stylised [`tabu`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabu) environments. `ot-tableau` offers dashed lines between constraints (=columns), which are marked by `:`. However, if those are used when `siunitx` is also loaded, this error is produced:

```
Package array Error: Illegal pream-token (:): 'c' used. \begin{tableau}{c:c|c}
```

The column separator `:` is defined as

```latex
\newcolumntype{:}{|[dashed]}
```

in `ot-tableau.sty` (line 147). Trying to use `|[dashed]` in the column definition fails, and so does sending the dashed line to another column definition, like `\newcolumntype{B}{|[dashed]}` (for "border").

I was unable to find reference to this issue anywhere or to contact `ot-tableau`'s author.

MNWE:

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{ot-tableau}

\begin{document}
\begin{tableau}{c:c|c}
    \inp{\ips{stap}}    \const{*Complex}    \const{Anchor-IO}   \const{Contiguity-IO}
    \cand{stap}     \vio{*!}    \vio{}  \vio{}  
    \cand[\Optimal]{sap}    \vio{}  \vio{}  \vio{*} 
    \cand{tap}  \vio{}  \vio{*!}    \vio{} 
\end{tableau}
\end{document}
```

Comment: tabu is broken and incompatible with a current latex. You won't find many people willing to debug an issue with it. See the readme here: https://github.com/tabu-issues-for-future-maintainer/tabu

Comment: I have a feeling I know where the issue lies, but the key is that it's fine with upcoming v3 of `siunitx` (to be released this month) doesn't have the problem

Comment: BTW, the example as given doesn't compile cleanly even without `siunitx`

Comment: @JosephWright thanks, I'll leave this issue open until the release of v3. Looking forward to this release! (Sorry about the syntax error in the MWNE, corrected that now)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite likely that it was `tabu` that was causing the problem. I've updated the package to avoid `tabu`, and your MNWE is now an MWE. :-) I've submitted the update to CTAN, and it's also on [GitHub](https://github.com/adamb924/ot-tableau) now.